# Android - is verifying certificate hashes the best way to prevent unauthorised app clones?

Tags: android, hash, certificate, digital-signature

I'm working on an app which communicates with a PHP server to get some data, based on which the app performs various tasks. I want to prevent APK crackers from making unauthorized versions of my app.

I'm using this method to get the certificate hashes of the package which will be sent to and verified by the server before providing any data.

```
private String getKeyHash(String hashStrategy) {
    PackageInfo info;
    String hash = "not_init";
    try {
        info = getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashStrategy);
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            hash = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("name not found" , e.toString());
        hash = "error";
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm" , e.toString());
        hash = "error";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception" , e.toString());
        hash = "error";
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Is this the best way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to prevent APK crackers from making unauthorized versions of my app.

That is impractical.

> Is this the best way to achieve the desired result?

That might stop a few people. I would expect that most attackers will modify the code to send the correct value in the Web service calls.